# Java - JOptionPane crashes when opened on one class, but not on another

Tags: java, crash

When I try to show a message dialogue from JOptionPane, both windows become unresponsive if I'm trying to access it from another class. It works if I do it from the main class, but if I try to use it from my SettingsWindow jframe it crashes.

```
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())>=Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText())) {
                MainClass.vars.setProperty("Width", textField.getText());
                MainClass.vars.setProperty("Height", textField_1.getText());
                MainClass.savePrefs();
                optionsWindow.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Height cannot be larger than width!");
                //MainClass.showMessage("Height cannot be larger than width!");
            }
        }
    });
    btnSave.setBounds(10, 168, 284, 24);
    jp.add(btnSave);
```

I tried accessing it via a method from the main class, but that crashes it too.

Comment: What do you mean by *it crashes*? Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: I figured it out. I guess you can't have more than 2 jframes open at once, and the JOptionPane was a jframe, so when I opened it it crashed. It would just freeze and the window wouldn't respond

Comment: You *can* have multiple frames open. Is an exception being thrown?